# PowerPivot : Pull data from a webservice

Tags: powerpivot

I try to pull the data from a web service to power pivot.  The web service supports a RESTful interface, meaning it uses HTTP GET requests, and returns an XML response.The HTTP Authorization Header needs to include the username and password. It utilizes the "Basic" authentication mechanism.

I tried to create a ODatafeed connection by providing url. In advanced settings, I have given username, pwd and set Basic authentication. What other settings should I set in Advanced settings. Because, it is throwing a error  "Cannot connect to the specified feed. Verify the connection and try again. Reason: For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.".  My client API exposes a web service it gives response in xml format.

How can approach my goal here.

Thanks,

Raghav

Comment: Hi Raghav, any progress on this?

Comment: Hi Marko. I did not get solution for this. It would be great help if you can provide me a solution for this.

Comment: unfortunately dont have it..